# I get this error ( ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' ) even though i installed it

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

so I'm using visual studio code on my mac and I'm trying to run a python code but I keep having problems with installing libraries.
whenever i run the code i get this

```
(base) reema@Reemas-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/reema/Desktop/import pandas as pd.py" Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/reema/Desktop/import pandas as pd.py", line 1, in import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

even though when I install it again it says this

```
`(base) reema@Reemas-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.15.0)`
```

Comment: That pip corresponds to Anaconda’s Python. You seem to have several versions of Python installed. Can you see `pandas` in the output of `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip list`?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused that your pandas has been installed in anaconda environment instead of base environment (you run your code by using base python interpreter).

Use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the correct interpreter.

1. You can choose anaconda then run the code.
2. If you want to run the code in the base python interpreter. Use command `deactivate env_name` or open a new terminal window and install this package by using command 'pip install pandas'